# Electric dipole oscillation in a uniform electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

We have two charged balls of masses $m_1=m_2=15.0\,g$, and charges $+q_1=-q_2=0.800\,\mu C$, fixed to the ends of a very light rod of length $\ell$. The centre of the rod is mounted on a friction-free pivot, and the whole system is then immersed in a uniform electric field of magnitude $E=450\,\frac NC$ (pointing from left to right).

I want to determine the period of oscillation if the system is disturbed from its initial orientation by a small angle, and then the same thing but when $m_2'=2m_1$.

[image]

Originally, the problem that I am dealing with doesn't mention whether the setup is horizontal (no need to consider gravity), or vertical. I am including gravity, though, because, in its absence, the result is the same as when it is present but the masses are equal.

Using $\sum\tau=I\ddot\theta$ about the pivot, I get:
$$\frac{\ell}{2}g\left(m_2-m_1\right)\cos\theta-\ell qE\sin\theta=(m_1+m_2)\frac{\ell^2}{4}\ddot\theta$$
You can see how gravity's contribution vanishes if the masses are equal (or if we consider that we are looking at the setup from above).

Consider the case where we are looking at the setup from above (no influence from gravity):
Using the small angle approximation, we take $\theta=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$, which gives us that $\omega^2=\frac{4\pi^2}{T^2}=\frac{4qE}{(m_1+m_2)\ell}$, or, $T=\pi\sqrt{\frac{(m_1+m_2)\ell}{qE}}$.
My homework platform is rejecting my solution when I put $m_2=2m_1$, so I guessed that it should be the other way (with gravitational influence).

Using the small angle approximation, we get:
$$\frac{\ell}{2}g\left(m_2-m_1\right)-\ell qE\theta=(m_1+m_2)\frac{\ell^2}{4}\ddot\theta$$
But the solution for this differential equation is not a trigonometric function.

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed a trigonometric function. The solution in this case has an additional constant term. Due to the differing masses, the equilibrium angle will not be 0 degrees with respect to the horizontal (as in the case of $m_1 = m_2$).

**A basic example of this**:
An oscillating mass hanging vertically from a ceiling attached to a spring has a sinusoidal motion and thus a sinusoidal solution.

The equation of motion of a mass $m$ is:
$mg - ky = m \ddot{y} $

If you are stuck on the constant force of gravity, that only changes the equilibrium position and so a trig solution still exists. Ignoring the constant term since that only affects the equilibrium position, we find that the angular frequency $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$.

Comment: right, I solved the equation by putting $f=a-b\theta$, which gives us the same oscillation period. i'm perplexed as to why my homework platform is rejecting it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your differential equation: in general, you can solve such ODEs by using the statement that
$\theta(t) = f(t) + \phi(t)$
Where $f(t)$ are the solutions of the homogenous differential equation:
$a \ddot{\theta} + b \dot{\theta} + cy = 0 $ which in this case gives us a harmonic oscilator (since the ODE is of second order we have two general solutions: the $\sin$ and $\cos$).
And where $\phi(t)$ is just a particular solution of the full differential equation: add an extra constant term to the general solution $f(t) + C$, plug in and solve for $C$.

Comment: yep, thank you. i have solved it!